# Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND) with MS-MPI on CLion

Tags: c, cmake, mpi

I've started a fresh C project with CLion and wanted to use MPI. Since I am on Windows, I installed MS-MPI (the MSMPI and the SDK), and have my CMakeLists.txt as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(ppc)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

find_package(MPI REQUIRED)
add_executable(ppc main.c)
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE MPI::MPI_C)
```

The problem is that whenever I try to import/reload the project, I get the following error:

```
C:\Users\frani\AppData\Local\JetBrains\CLion2020.2\cygwin_cmake\bin\cmake.exe -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/make.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/g++.exe -G "CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles" /cygdrive/d/Dev/CLionProjects/ppc
-- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_HEADER_DIR MPI_C_WORKS) 
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_HEADER_DIR MPI_CXX_WORKS) 
CMake Error at /cygdrive/c/Users/frani/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.2/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.17.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:164 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)

      Reason given by package: MPI component 'Fortran' was requested, but language Fortran is not enabled.  

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /cygdrive/c/Users/frani/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.2/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.17.3/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:445 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /cygdrive/c/Users/frani/AppData/Local/JetBrains/CLion2020.2/cygwin_cmake/share/cmake-3.17.3/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1717 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/cygdrive/d/Dev/CLionProjects/ppc/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/cygdrive/d/Dev/CLionProjects/ppc/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".

[Finished]
```

What is wrong with my file?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this after your `project` declaration:

```
enable_language(Fortran)
```

(https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/enable_language.html)

Comment: I tried that, had to set the Fortran compiler (`set(CMAKE_Fortran_COMPILER "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Simply Fortran 3\\mingw-w64\\bin\\gfortran.exe")`), but then it errored by not being able to pass the windows \ char ([error](https://gist.github.com/Eufranio/d1bad3bf533a5914d7a478410d0daadf))

Comment: You have to escape spaces in compiler path