# Why is CMake unable to find MPI?

Tags: cmake, openmpi

I'm trying to install software from GitHub (GLSLIM, [link](https://github.com/echristakopoulou/glslim)) on Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Among the requirements, there are both MPI and CMake. I installed both of them with the libraries, which I've found on the websites ([CMake](https://cmake.org/download/) and [openmpi](https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v4.1/)). When I try to do the GLSLIM build, I get the following error:

```
-- Could NOT find MPI_C (missing: MPI_C_LIB_NAMES MPI_C_WORKS) 
-- Could NOT find MPI_CXX (missing: MPI_CXX_LIB_NAMES MPI_CXX_WORKS) 
CMake Error at /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:230 (message):
  Could NOT find MPI (missing: MPI_C_FOUND MPI_CXX_FOUND)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:594 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  /usr/local/share/cmake-3.23/Modules/FindMPI.cmake:1830 (find_package_handle_standard_args)

  CMakeLists.txt:6 (find_package)
```

I've searched on the Internet for possible solutions, and I've found plenty of similar problems. For example, those are some related StackOverflow questions: [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65720826/cmake-does-not-find-mpi-for-fortran), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68474236/cmake-does-not-find-mpi-headers-for-c), [third](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65015385/could-not-find-mpi-missing-mpi-c-found-mpi-cxx-found-with-ms-mpi-on-clion), [fourth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71115317/how-do-i-resolve-the-cmake-error-could-not-find-mpi), etc.

Anyway, none of them solved my problem, nor did it seem strictly related to it.

I don't know where to start in trying to find a solution. Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: `I installed` How exactly have you installed MPI?

Comment: I downloaded the last stable source from the link, and I followed the instructions in the `INSTALL` file step by step @KamilCuk

Comment: Don't you have openmpi in your _system distribution package manager_? Did you follow `User Builds`? What options did you gave to `./configure`

Comment: Nope, I have Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, so I use apt. I tried to install it with apt but it doesn't install all the libraries.

Comment: You have ubuntu - one of the most popular linux distribution - don't you have like https://www.howtoinstall.me/ubuntu/18-04/libopenmpi-dev/ ? Do you have `/usr/local/lib/openmpi` directory with bunch of `.so` files inside?

Comment: It worked, thank you. I wonder why the installation process from the source code didn't work. I followed the instruction at this link https://www.open-mpi.org//faq/?category=building#easy-build. Anyway, if you want to add the solution as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: I'm voting to close because this question is unanswerable as-posed. Installing the system packages doesn't reveal why the from-source build failed, though it does let OP continue writing MPI code (which is good!).

Answer (score 0):

maybe use the following:

`sudo rm -f /etc/aternatives/mpi* /var/lib/dpkg/alternatives/mpi*`

`sudo apt install openmpi-bin`

[(Source)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openmpi/+bug/1970985)